# iterator and type checking

Tags: python, types

How do I determine the ith element type in such code:

```
for i in some_iterable:
    if type(i) is some_class:
        print "foobar"
```

it is currently not working as I expect the type of i is being returned as iterator not the actual value stored underneath.

Comment: Type of `i` **is** the type of the value stored in `some_iterable`. So if `some_iterable = [1,'2',[3]]` the type of `i` would respectively be `int`, `str`, and `list`. What do you mean with the type being an `iterator`?

Comment: What is `some_iterable`? *What* are you iterating over?

Comment: well clearly it is not working for me, I yet don't know why, but I have some values in he array of type some_class and when I do this check it will not take the if action...And when I print the I it is stated: <foobar instance at 0x25f85f0>

Comment: As numerous other answers have answered, if `print i` returns `<foobar instance at 0x25f85f0>`, then `isinstance(i,foobar)` should return `True`. You probably need to tell us more on: What does some_iterable contain? What do you expect?

Comment: And until you tell us what `some_iterable` is, it will remain a mystery.

Comment: are you sure this object is not build with a class derived from `foobar` ? in this case `type(x) is foobar` checks the actual type of the object and returns false if the object is from a derived class, whereas `isinstance(x,foobar)` return true even for derived object.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, someone just overwritten the str method of underneath class to print its content so it is not actually the some_class but container of some_class, thanks for the answers I would never be able to sort it out without them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mistake of the OP not related with the actual question. He accepts an answer after realizing his data was not correct. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking types in python is done with `isinstance()` builtin function: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance

Like this:

```
>>> isinstance('a',basestring)
True
>>> isinstance(['a'],list)
True
```

Comment: It does the same as "type is some_class", so it doesn't return true when I pass the "i" to it.

Comment: `if isinstance(i, some_class):`.

Comment: yes I have done this kind of check and it Is not executing the if code.

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried using `isinstance`? As I said in the comment section also, if `print i` returns `<foobar instance at 0x25f85f0>`, then `isinstance(i,foobar)` should return `True`. You probably need to tell us more on: What does `some_iterable` contain? What do you expect?

Comment: as I mentioned in the comments It was the wrong type I was checking but your answer convince me that I am doing the right thing so as It was first I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `isintance(i,someclass)`

```
>>> class C(object):
 pass

>>> class D(C):
 pass
>>> type(C) == C
False
>>> type(C()) == C
True
>>> type(D()) == C
False
>>> isinstance(C(),C)
True
>>> isinstance(D(),C)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure about the contents/structure of your iterable? Because this example works fine for me:

```
strings_and_nums = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c']

for element in strings_and_nums:
    if type(element) is str:
        print "String"
    else:
        print "Something else"
# Output:
String
Something else
String
Something else
String
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to do it , `isinstance(i,someclass)`

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, and you haven't been clear in the slightest, `i` is an iterable and you want to check the types of what it yields.

You need to get a value, first:

```
v = next(i)
```

then you should put it back:

```
from itertools import chain

i = chain([v], i)
```

then you can do the `isinstance` check on `v`:

```
isinstance(v, sometype)
```

Is that it?

---

Note that if there's a chance that the iterable is 0 long, you can't determine it's type. You can stop it from breaking, though:

```
try:
    v = next(i)

except StopIteration:
    what_to_do_if_no_elements()

else:
    i = chain([v], i)
    if isinstance(v, sometype):
        ...
```